# How old is Optimus Prime?

Tags: transformers, age, optimus-prime

**How old is Optimus Prime?** *If it is measurable.

Not talking about the *aging* process (like, is he a child, an adult, or elderly); but how many years/aeons/Cybertronian-years old is he?

I suppose, in effect, what Ι'm asking is: **how long has he been around?**

*Please provide canon only answers.*

Comment: Sorry for the down vote but honestly, this could be answered by a 2 minute google search.

Comment: @Morgan - Not really. I just googled it myself. Only one link (other than this very question) that attempt to answer the question, and only does it using one continuity.

Comment: @Morgan I appreciate you explaining the down-vote though, that is not common :)

Comment: I remember from *Transformers Armada* that he was created by Unicorn just after the Big Bang. But, I am not 100% certain. It can be just after great cybertron war.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We don't know the exact number, but we do know that it is in the millions of years.

***In the 1984 cartoon series***, the Aerialbots travel 9 million years to the past and meet Orion Pax and witness him being rebuilt into Optimus Prime. So if we consider Optimus's age just from that point onward then he's 9 million years old and possibly much older if we figure in his time as Orion. However, he was in stasis on Earth when the Ark crashed for around 4 million years. **So let's call him 5 million years old.**

***In the IDW comics continuity***, the earliest mention of Orion Pax was him as a police officer serving Nominus Prime, then he becomes Optimus Prime during the reign of Zeta Prime. We don't have any dates. But we do know that Nova Prime (who predated all of those Primes) left Cybertron 6 million years ago. We also know from Transformers #22 that Optimus Prime and Megatron engaged in the battle of Sherma Bridge 4 million years ago. **So his age as Optimus Prime is between 4-6 million years**, and again could be much longer if we figure out his time as Orion Pax.

Comment: the statistics is strong on this one.. +1

Answer (score -1):

Optimus prime is over 25 million years  old if you factor in how old he was as orion pax as a police officer as he had to be at least 5,000,000 years old averaging how old a police officer would be with the ages of the auto bots

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE. Do you have a source for any of the information in your answer?

Comment: You can't really extrapolate human aging into Cybertronian aging. Bots don't need to be a certain *age* to do stuff. For instance the war-ear MTOs (Made To Order) were quickly manufactured and thrust into the war after a brief education and training period.