# Is Optimus Prime as we know him one of the Thirteen Original Primes?

Tags: transformers, optimus-prime

In the Aligned continuity, one of the Thirteen Original Primes, Optimus Prime, chose to be reborn as an ordinary Cybertronian to live among the ones soon to be born from the Well of Allsparks. He was reborn as Orion Pax, and Alpha Trion, one of the Thirteen, observed the process, identified him, and took him under his personal mentorship.

Eons later, Orion Pax & Megatron led a movement & petitioned the Council to reform Cybertronian society, but the movement was splintered when the Council accepted Orion's pleas & appointed him to be a new Prime, soon igniting the Great War. Only much later, when Orion travelled to Cybertron's core, did Primus restore Orion back into Optimus Prime.

However, it seems to be uncertain how much Optimus remembers of his original life, before his first rebirth. In any case:

- Is Optimus Prime during the War for Cybertron & the events of *Transformers: Prime* known by others to be one of the Thirteen Original Primes? Does he himself know and/or consider himself as such?
- Although they are of the same spark, is the first Optimus Prime that fought in the first war of the Thirteen Primes against Unicron and the second Optimus Prime who led the Autobots against the Decepticons considered to be one and the same, or are they two different entities, both empowered to be a Prime by Primus, both sharing the same name, but nothing more?

Comment: Related: [How old is Optimus Prime?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/55358/21267)

Comment: wth? I don't understand any of that - is this cartoon, comic, movies, books?

Comment: @NKCampbell As thegreatjedi talks about the aligned continuity I daresay all 4 of those (as they tried to align it into a complete multiverse a while back which they just call the aligned continuity).

Answer (score 2):

According to [wiki](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Optimus_Prime_(WFC)) optimus prime is also known as **the last prime**. From the given source it says that he partially remembered his past as Orion Pax.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when he received the Matrix of Leadership he had gotten his memories back. During the Prime series when he empty the matrix, he lost his memories of being a Prime.

When he did regain his memories a few episodes later, he clearly remembers being the Autobot leader Optimus Prime. But that was while he had the Matrix with him though.

Back with the 13 Primes, it was Prima who had the Matrix of Leadership. While it did contain memories for both Prima and Primus (the Matrix of Leadership does have a part of Primus's spark), it isn't quite clear if Optimus remembers himself as being one of 13 Primes (from his point of view) rather than just knowing he is one of them (from other's point of view).

I don't see why both the thirteenth and Optimus would be two different entities since the two share the exact same spark.

As Alpha Trion wrote:

> By the third day, larger creatures began to appear, and then Prima called me over to witness thing he was eager to point to me...at the head of them, slowly pacing forward with an expression of surprise and wonder, came the figure we thought we would never see and wondered if we would ever recognize. I recognize him immediately, although he looked nothing like *Thirteen*- he was far smaller and simpler, an altogether unimposing bot of no particular outstanding feature other than the unique signature of his spark.

Comment: Where is that quote from?