# Source of a Quote by Alpha Trion

Tags: transformers, optimus-prime

> By the third day, larger creatures began to appear, and then Prima
>   called me over to witness thing he was eager to point to me...at the
>   head of them, slowly pacing forward with an expression of surprise and
>   wonder, came the figure we thought we would never see and wondered if
>   we would ever recognize. I recognize him immediately, although he
>   looked nothing like Thirteen- he was far smaller and simpler, an
>   altogether unimposing bot of no particular outstanding feature other
>   than the unique signature of his spark.

Does anyone know where this quote was taken from?

I first saw it referenced here: [Is Optimus Prime as we know him one of the Thirteen Original Primes?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135147/is-optimus-prime-as-we-know-him-one-of-the-thirteen-original-primes)

TransKas is responding to an inquiry about the Aligned continuity and whether or not Optimus remembers his original life.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a quote from the prose novel [Transformers: The Covenant of Primus](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Transformers:_The_Covenant_of_Primus).

[image]

I've not got a copy, but it's mentioned (and quoted) [here](https://farfalleh.tumblr.com/post/100863288975/right-lets-fucking-do-it-ive-got-my-copy-of).
Warning, NSFW (naughty words).