# How old would Bumblebee be in Transformers (2007)?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series, transformers-2007

I have read that Optimus Prime (not counting his previous years as Orion Pax) would be between 4-6 million years old (or much more). My question now is, would Bumblebee be younger than him? Approximately how many years younger?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you quote, or reference the source for Optimus Prime's age?  It might help track down the age of the other Autobots.

Comment: Of course, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/55358/165312 The age of the autobots and other characters is something that has made me curious for years

Comment: I don’t think Orion Pax is a thing in the live-action series.

Comment: If Optimus Prime is multiple millions of years old, it causes one to wonder why he hasn't run out of "I will never do that again" (underestimate humans, betray the Autobots, etc.)  statements long before any of the events portrayed in the films.